# Password recovery of Brocade Silkworm 3200 fibre switch

Tags: switch

We have a Brocade Silkworm 3200 fibre switch that we can not locate the administrator password.  Is there a way to reset this, or is there a default ID that we can use to gain access to the device?

Or is there a way to do a hard reset on the device to get it back to factory defaults?  Any way possible that we can get back into this device?

Answer (score 0):

For the 2400 series, may work for other models.

> In the event that a user changes a password and forgets it, the password can be reinitialized.
>
> To reset factory defaults
>
> 1. Connect the serial port to a PC/workstation using a standard serial cable with a DB9 connector.
> 2. Establish a connection to the shell.
>
> The prompt is displayed as switchName:userName>
>
> For example: sw4:admin>
>
> 3 . Enter the configDefault command.

[Source of Information](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1275993&page=15)

[PDF document for the 2400, see page 21](http://www.filibeto.org/sun/lib/nonsun/brocade/manuals/refmanual/9846182982400.pdf)

[PDF for the 3200](http://www.bralos.com/files/manuals/brocade/3200hwref.pdf)  Default account and password is admin > password